# OTRS Generic Interface (Search ticket) - Array for URL Query Param

Tags: curl, otrs

Scroll down @ [OTRS Admin Documentation](http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/genericinterface.html) : Here you find the curl statement for search ticket operations.

```
curl "http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=agent&Password=123&Queue=Postmaster"
```

Does someone knows how to search for 2 different queues in one curl statement? Yes I can do 2 curl requests, but if it is possible one single request would be better.

I tried some URL query param array stuff, but nothing works, e.g.

```
//just second Queue is used!!!
curl "http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=agent&Password=123&Queue=Postmaster&Queue=Postmaster2"

//
curl "http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=agent&Password=123&Queue[]=Postmaster&Queue[]=Postmaster2"

//
curl "http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=agent&Password=123&Queue=Postmaster,Postmaster2"

    //
curl "http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=agent&Password=123&Queue=[Postmaster,Postmaster2]"
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure it's possible using a GET method if I look briefly at the OTRS sources. But there is a way to supply a parameter more than once if you switch the TicketSearch operation to POST and supply the query parameters via JSON.

Configuring the web service is relatively easy; in OTRS you should navigate to Admin > Web Services. Select the 'Rest" web service. Choose the 'Configure' button next to the network transport ('HTTP::REST').

Now update the route mapping for TicketSearch from `Ticket` to something unique, for example `TicketSearch`. Otherwise, POST requests to the `Ticket` route will end up in the TicketCreate operation. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Now you can pass the parameters as a JSON document. The `curl` example looks like this:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"Queues": ["Bar", "Foo"]}' \
"http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/TicketSearch?UserLogin=test&Password=test"
```

Please note that if one of your queue names does not exist, the search will return no tickets.

Comment: The example from the docs with the "Queue=*" query param didn't work at all for me (searching for a single queue). This method is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, and as I felt on that thread while searching for the same issue:

I made it working by using the filter "Queues", instead of "Queue", and simply repeating the parameter:

```
> curl -k "https://otrs02.telsys.ch/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=qmorrier***&Password=***&Queues=Nouveaux&Queues=Raw"
{"TicketID":["2","1"]}

> curl -k "https://otrs02.telsys.ch/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=qmorrier***&Password=***&Queues=Nouveaux&Queues=Raw&Queues=Niveau%201"
{"TicketID":["3","2","1"]}
```

I'm currently running OTRS 6.0.25 Community Edition